# Sum cells factored according to criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

When a cell in A2:A100 meets a certain condition, I want to multiply a corresponding value by a factor and, for a different condition, the corresponding value by a different factor, eg when A2=:

```
"Banana" then B2*C2 but when  
"Apple"  then B2*C3 but when  
"Pear"   then B2*C4
```

and sum these results, all in a single cell.

So when A2="Banana" and A3="Pear" I want to have this: `=B2*C2+B3*C4`.

The corresponding values for the criteria in ColumnA are in ColumnB (matching row) and C2, C3 and C4 contain the factors appropriate to the criteria.

I have tried a big formula, but that took me like forever, and when I enter more values in ColumnA I have to adjust that formula.

Comment: I cant use vba or visual basic, i have no real experience in programming, only in excel

Comment: yeah thats exactly what i want

Comment: no i dont want the outcomes in a column, i want to sum them all up and put them all in 1 cell but if that isn't possible i can think in a way like that

Comment: YEAH, it does! thanks for the help already, but if there would be a way to do it in once it would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Apple",B:B)*C3+SUMIF(A:A,"Banana",B:B)*C2+SUMIF(A:A,"Pear",B:B)*C4
```

oops - but with semicolons instead of commas!

Comment: As long as the C2:C4 is a contiguous range, as per the example then you could also this version `=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C4;SUMIF(A:A;{"Banana";"Apple";"Pear"};B:B))`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A2="banana";B2*C2;IF(A2="apple";B2*C3;B2*C4))
```

or do you need something simular but for 100+ cases?

Comment: i need like that but for the 100+ cases

Comment: are you able to use Macros/VBA (Visual Basic for Application) ?

Comment: this is a tiny part of the big formula i used, i changed it so it fits the example:
=(SUM(IF(A2="Apple";B2*C2;IF(A2="Banana";B2*C3;IF(A2="Pear";B2*C4;IF(A2="Orange";B2*C5;0))));IF(A3="Apple";B3*C2;IF(A3="Banana";B3*C3;IF(A3="Pear";B3*C4;IF(A3="Orange";B3*C5;0))));IF(A4="Apple";B4*C2;IF(A4="Banana";B4*C3;IF(A4="Pear";B4*C4;IF(A4="Orange";B4*C5;0))));IF(A5="Apple";B5*C2;IF(A5="Banana";B5*C3;IF(A5="Pear";B5*C4;IF(A5="Orange";B5*C5;0))))

Comment: i dont think i can use those, but if you explain what it is maybe i can :$

Comment: press Alt+F11 in Excel -- will be opened Microsoft Visual Basic for Application. You could write normal code there.

Comment: do you need any programming experience/skills for that?

Comment: yes, you need to know VBA. otherwise, you need to use your very long formula

Comment: Ahh, i will try to improve my excel skills with vba for in the future, but in this case the SUMIF below did the trick, but thank you for learning me programming in excel :)